# Facebook infinite loop

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have been googleing this and looked on stackoverflow for a answer but havent found anything that works for me.

i have checked below the !The user probably has cookies disabled, i have tried this and in multiple browsers same problem.

I am using facebook sdk for a third party login but everything i run the code i get the following

```
The webpage at https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=466044326753518&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.users36.interdns.co.uk%2Fconnect_facebook&display=page&fbconnect=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.users36.interdns.co.uk%2Fconnect_facebook&return_session=1&session_version=3&v=1.0&req_perms=user_birthday has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
```

Here is the url that it generates for the url

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=466044326753518&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.users36.interdns.co.uk%2Fconnect_facebook&display=page&fbconnect=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.users36.interdns.co.uk%2Fconnect_facebook&return_session=1&session_version=3&v=1.0&req_perms=user_birthday
```

I have tried many options but nothing seems to work. I am using codeigniter and i have my uri_protocol set to auto

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

if i set it to PATH_INFO it works

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

This is driving me crazy because it means i have to leave all my urls with index.php here is my .htaccess

```
    Options         +FollowSymLinks
Options         -Indexes 
DirectoryIndex  index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]  

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

I have read up that my hosting may not support path_info?

Can anyone shed some light on this i am also going to contact my hosting.

Thanks

Update it is redirecting between these two urls from the network tab in chrome.

```
http://example.users36.interdns.co.uk/connect_facebook?session=%7B%22session_key%22%3A%222.AQDZt8rGtuhgss40.3600.1345111200.0-680410999%22%2C%22uid%22%3A%22680410999%22%2C%22expires%22%3A1345111200%2C%22secret%22%3A%22CCHtz17wmFCRRNApLUM6zQ__%22%2C%22base_domain%22%3A%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fexample.users36.interdns.co.uk%5C%2F%22%2C%22access_token%22%3A%22AAAGn3WaLtO4BAFA8HOMbdJY1ouKwIZCIfOxHqnJEjU2beEkARUeQIJ24J3Qsw93UWJSPJF7qGorkBXWeaP0TlBV2UKWuBvrjqIn2jJgZDZD%22%2C%22sig%22%3A%220e7a4c9d172006abc642756617cbe058%22%7D
```

---

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=466044326753518&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.users36.interdns.co.uk%2Fconnect_facebook&display=page&fbconnect=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.users36.interdns.co.uk%2Fconnect_facebook&return_session=1&session_version=3&v=1.0&req_perms=user_birthday
```

When i have it set to path_info it works and here is the network response

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=466044326753518&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.users36.interdns.co.uk%2Findex.php%2Fconnect_facebook&display=page&fbconnect=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.users36.interdns.co.uk%2Findex.php%2Fconnect_facebook&return_session=1&session_version=3&v=1.0&req_perms=user_birthday
```

---

```
http://example.users36.interdns.co.uk/index.php/connect_facebook?session=%7B%22session_key%22%3A%222.AQDZt8rGtuhgss40.3600.1345111200.0-680410999%22%2C%22uid%22%3A%22680410999%22%2C%22expires%22%3A1345111200%2C%22secret%22%3A%22CCHtz17wmFCRRNApLUM6zQ__%22%2C%22base_domain%22%3A%22http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fexample.users36.interdns.co.uk%5C%2F%22%2C%22access_token%22%3A%22AAAGn3WaLtO4BAFA8HOMbdJY1ouKwIZCIfOxHqnJEjU2beEkARUeQIJ24J3Qsw93UWJSPJF7qGorkBXWeaP0TlBV2UKWuBvrjqIn2jJgZDZD%22%2C%22sig%22%3A%220e7a4c9d172006abc642756617cbe058%22%7D
```

Comment: The two areas (FB SDK and PATH_INFO) are, on the face of it, completely unrelated. Are you certain this fixes it, and not simply that you are looking at a cached copy of the page when you have it set to auto? Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Hi Dave tried clearing my browser cache and tried the same thing in other browsers in a nutshell i need codeigniter to work with path_info and no index.php in the url, and the way it stands at the moment the only way i can get codeigniter to work without index.php is to have uri_protocol set to auto?

Comment: In that case it seems likey that your return URL `http://example.users36.interdns.co.uk/connect_facebook` is redirecting you back to FB, which is in turn redirecting back to you return URL... and so on. Either that or your return URL is continuously redirecting to itself. Open Chrome, get the developer tools up (press F12), click the Network tab, click the "Preserve log upon navigation" button (little grey circle icon at the bottom right, will turn red when enabled) and then try your login - you can now view the request chain to see what's actually happening, and report your findings back ;-)

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure `index.php?/$1` in the RewriteRule should just be `index.php/$1` - the `?` turns it into a query string, not a path info string.

Comment: Hi dave i have updated my answer to show the results the first set it just loop between those two urls none stop until it crashes and the second one is when it works, they both seem identical to me apart from the index.php? i have to keep the ? in the .htaccess to get it working else i get no input specified i think it my hosting does not support cgi.path_info see what they come back with now

Comment: Well if you're in an infinite loop between your site and FB then the problem is that inside the `connect_facebook` code, you are not correctly handling the response and you are issuing a redirect again. Can you show the code that should be executed when you handle the response? Basically, the code that should be reached when I request `http://example.users36.interdns.co.uk/connect_facebook` - which, by the way, gives me a 404, but I guess you have modified the URL for posting here